# Removing Projects while working in wildfly in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, jsp, wildfly

I am using Eclipse Neon and I am using the wildfly server.

Now the main problem is that each time I do some changes in my code and view it in Google Chrome sometimes the changes show up simultaneously and most of the times I have to refresh 3 to 4 times to see the change taking place.

Not only this most of the times I have to remove my project from the server and again run it to see the changes like this.[image]

Of course removing the cache files in Google Chrome helps but I don't want to do that everytime.

> I know about full publish but it also doesn't help most of the times.Sometimes my only solution is to remove and restart the server or the project.Is there any solution to it?

Sorry it may feel a little low question but I am quite new to this server side work so any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Edit: Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you install a plugin called "cache killer" in chrome and activate it, it will always pull the new page from server, hope you will get latest changes.

Comment: But after that isn't it that no cache files from any other sites will ever be saved in chrome?